# Does the proximity rule for hand washing water extend to b'racha precedence?

Tags: halacha, blessing, priorities, bread, hamotzi-beracha

1. Assuming that one must wash one's hands before eating bread [unless the water is *very far away*](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%92#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A7.D7.A1.D7.92_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.91), and
2. assuming one is near water, and
3. assuming that [the highest precedence *b'racha* is the *b'racha* for bread](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A8.D7.99.D7.90_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.90) - *hamotzi lechem min ha'aretz*, and
4. assuming that one has bread as well as food demanding other *b'rachos*, and
5. assuming one [has every intention and desire to eat the bread](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A8.D7.99.D7.90_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.92), and
6. assuming the water is sufficiently inconvenient *at the moment of decision* to make washing a slight annoyance,

is one required to eat the bread first, or is the slight annoyance enough to bump the other food up the precedence ladder, deferring the bread until later?

---

**UPDATE**: Now with sources!

Comment: I intend to eat the bread, but not now? Then how is it different than having a sandwich and an apple in my lunch and eating the apple earlier in the day?

Comment: The *only* reason for delaying the bread is the slight annoyance of walking away and washing. Indeed I would eat the bread _right now_ if I'd already washed. Your question is my question.

Comment: So... I'm still not going to eat the sandwich now. How is this a question? If I'm going to get up and wash, then I get up and wash first. If I'm annoyed enough NOT to (even though I want to) then I don't wash...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky If you have a source for your last part that could be a good answer.